# How to send a file using AJAX call without form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I need to send a PDF file from ajax to call to Django server, without form data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send your files as raw file buffer as follows:

```
var input = $('#input');

input.change(function(event) {
  var file = this.files[0];
  if (!file) return;

  return $.ajax({
    url: '/django-route', // your route to process the file
    type: 'POST', //
    data: file,
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/octet-stream', // set Content-Type header
    success: function(respnse) {
      // do something
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // do something else
    }
  });
});
```

If you need to track the progress of your file upload, add the `xhr` to `$.ajax()` options:

```
xhr: function() {
  var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
      var progress = Math.floor(10000 * event.loaded / event.total) / 10000;
      console.log(progress); // 0.2536 (25.36%)
    }
  }, false);
  xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
      var progress = Math.floor(10000 * event.loaded / event.total) / 10000;
      console.log(progress);
    }
  }, false);
  return xhr;
}
```

Comment: No .. I am not getting the file, in request.FILES. It is showing as empty.

Please check at your end

(Pdb) request.FILES
<MultiValueDict: {}>

Comment: Since the question is js-specific (not django-specific), the answer is perfectly valid. You are not getting any files, since I guess django file parser middleware is by default configured to accept `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` requests. Check `response.body`, the buffer should be there.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I encountered with Django (rest framework specifically) were the Parser classes. If you want to send octet-stream then use a parser class :

```
class StreamParser(BaseParser):
    media_type = 'octet-stream'
    def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
        return stream.read()
```

and then on your view class:

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
"""
A view that can accept POST requests with JSON content.
"""
parser_classes = [StreamParser]

def post(self, request, format=None):
    return Response({'received data': request.data})
```

Finally do not forget to include django restframework and the following entry in `settings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
     ]
}
```

It is all explained [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#custom-parsers).

Hope it helps !